# How to know plain text of :encrypted_password, in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords

If i use has_secure_password, i have whitelist are: `password`, `password_confirmation`, and `password_digest`. With `password` is the plain text of `password_digest`, which was encrypted by bcrypt.

But when i use devise with my user model, it has only `encrypted_password` field, I don't know how to know plain text of `password`. The schema doesn't has `password field`. I uasually use rails consle to debug. So anyone can help me how to know the plain text of `encrypted_password`.

Comment: That is the whole point, you should not know it. Why do you want/need to know it in your app?

Comment: `bcrypt` is actually not encryption, just another exampl of bad naming. It is a one-way cryptographically secure hash, it is not reversible,It is one right way to handle passwords.

Comment: It not in my apps, in the dev enviroment , sometimes i forget my password, i can't login to my app to test the view. So I try to get its plain text. But there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the plain-text password from the encrypted_password field.
But, you can change the password and set it to any string you choose by setting the `password` attribute of the user model. For example:

```
user = User.find(34)
user.password = "some password"
user.save!
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? Else, there's no way for me to improve this and future answers.

Comment: It's right. No way to get the plain text of password.
When i try `user.passowd` always it return `nil` . But update password with command `user.password = 'my password'` , it works.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using a hash function to store a password is that there is no way to reverse the hash function. This is why it is called a one way function.

The only way is to try all possible passwords until the hash function results in the same hash as you have. This what the passwords crackers like hashcat do, but they use GPUs the parallelise the process. If you have chosen a long and complex password then the time to do this will be longer than would be feasible for an attacker to complete.

Using a hash function that is expensive in either CPU time or memory requirement, is also important in protecting the passwords. See Password Key Derivation functions.

Comment: Is it use MD5 or SHA to encrypted?