# Rails 5 fetch curret_login password from session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got Rails 5 app with devise gem. When a user is logged in he can create a new `registrant` via `registrant/new` and the following action in the controller:

```
class RegistrantsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    authorize Registrant
    @registrant = Registrant.new
  end
end
```

But before this is created I would like to check via API call that this user does not already exist in the parent application. To do this I have to do all the magic to get the `access_token` which requires the user's email and password.

How can I extract the password of the logged in user to pass it to some new method? What I tried to do is fetch password from `session` hash or from `current_login` directly but in both cases it showed me nil:

```
[1] pry(#<RegistrantsController>)> current_login
=> #<Login id: 12, email: "physician@test.com", created_at: "2022-01-13 14:05:26", updated_at: "2022-01-26 10:21:34", oauth_tokens: nil, email_source: nil, paper_entry: nil, password_changed_at: "2022-01-13 14:05:25", auth_strategy: "local", session_token: nil>
[2] pry(#<RegistrantsController>)> current_login.password
=> nil
[3] pry(#<RegistrantsController>)> session[:password]
=> nil
[4] pry(#<RegistrantsController>)> session[:current_login_password]
=> nil
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: you can't grab the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise does not provide a reader method around `password`, only a setter.

This is because the user password is encrypted and you cannot retrieve the associated plain text.

See:

[How to know plain text of :encrypted_password, in devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781119/how-to-know-plain-text-of-encrypted-password-in-devise)

> when i use devise with my user model, it has only encrypted_password field, I don't know how to know plain text of password.

In your example, the only thing you can retrieve is `current_user.encrypted_password` but I guess it will be of little to no use to check in your "parent application".

If you have a dependency to another API / application then you should think of another way of checking user existence (maybe on the parent app a `/users/:id` route that returns 404 if no user with this id is found).